# Статус задания в планировщике

Tags: java, планировщик-задач, quartz

День добрый. Использую quartz для java. Как получить статус выполнения задания. К примеру остановлено/запущено. Заранее спасибо.

Используемый код прилагаю.

```
package Tasks;

import org.quartz.*;
import org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory;

public class NewJobDateBorn {

private static JobDetail job;
private static Trigger trigger;
private static Scheduler sched;

public void creatNewJob() throws SchedulerException {
    job = JobBuilder
            .newJob(DateBornJob.class)
            .withIdentity("DateBornJob", "dateborn")
            .build();

    trigger = TriggerBuilder
            .newTrigger()
            .withIdentity("DateBornTrigger", "dateborn")
            .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder
                    .cronSchedule("0 10 0 1/1 * ? *"))
            .build();


    SchedulerFactory schedFact = new StdSchedulerFactory();
    sched = schedFact.getScheduler();
    sched.start();
    sched.scheduleJob(job,trigger);
}

public void removeJob() throws SchedulerException {
    sched.shutdown();
}
```

}

Comment: записывать в бд статус таска. Как вариант.

Comment: @Tsyklop а можете привести пример кода?

Comment: пример. Хм. ТУт скорее всего нужно писать свой некий контрол для заданий. Ну а статус можно через базу. Например при старте задачи записали в базу что `работает`, когда завершается `завершен`.